How to avoid the stiffness issue stopping the run while using NDSolve for different initial conditions?
I have been using the NDSolve for generating a Poincare section that obviously requires many different initial conditions ( randomised ). The trouble is that  depending on the ODE set, as I fiddle with the ODE parameters quite often the program fails as it encounters stiff/ singularity issues. Any way of countering this or at least bypassing those pesky initial conditions and automatically choose other initial conditions without stopping the build up of the Poincare section?

Could you upload a minimal working example?

it encounters stiff/ singularity issues Did you try StiffnessSwitching

Assuming you do not know beforehand which ICs are pesky, you could use Check[] to discard ones that generate the NDSolve::ndsz message.

Did you press the blue circle-i at the end of the message to get to a message ref page with examples and solution ideas?

Stiffness is a numerical problem; singular is a mathematics problem.  Do you know which you encountered.?  In any case, please provide more information.
